# Is $e^{-2x}\sinh x$ an acceptable state wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-states

I have the following function in the range $(0, \infty)$:

$$\psi(x)=e^{-2x}\sinh x$$

I would like to know if it is acceptable as a wavefunction. At $x = \infty$, we have $e^{-2x} = 0$ and $\sinh x = \infty$. Isn't this an idetermination?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Your wavefunction vanishes at $x=\infty$, since $e^{-2x}\sinh{x}=e^{-2x}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{2}$. This vanishes as $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\sinh{x}$ can be expressed as

$$\sinh{x}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}.$$

Thus, in the limit as $x$ becomes large, we have

$$e^{-2x}\sinh{x}=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{2}\longrightarrow 0.$$

However, this is not enough to determine that this function could be an appropriate wavefunction for some one-dimensional system. For that to be the case, we would require that this function be square integrable. Indeed,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,e^{-4x}\sinh^2{x}=\frac{1}{24}<\infty.$$

Thus, this function is perfectly valid as a quantum wavefunction.

Comment: You surely mean that $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-4x}\sinh^2{x}dx\leq \infty$.

Comment: Agree, you should consider $\int | \psi (x) |^{2} \, dx$ but not $\int \psi(x) \, dx$

Comment: @GK Regarding the edit you've suggested... I think it's not common to suggest edits to correct the content of the post. _Usually_, it'll be approved only if the author himself reviews your edit and thinks it's correct: other reviewers (in this case me) don't know if it's deliberate and hence need to reject it as 'conflicts with the author's intent'. Anyways, hopefully BobKnighton'll  see your comment and change that portion.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. I'll fix it immediately (jet lag getting the best of me).